# How to robocopy directories with spaces AND special characters in the name

Tags: robocopy

Hey there I'm running into an issue when trying to robocopy several thousand files to a destination folder that contains spaces and special characters.

Code:

```
robocopy "SOURCE" "\\arc\GLUONPREP\Market Centers\~1 FOR MC TEAM\Apparel Logos " *-1c.pdf /MT:64 /XX /R:1 /W:0 /S
```

Result:

```
    Started : Thursday, July 29, 2021 12:04:21 PM
   Source - [omitted for privacy]
     Dest - C:\Users\joshh\Centers\~1\

    Files : FOR
            MC

  Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #5 : "TEAM\Apparel"
```

I was reading that in order to handle spaces in directories, some have added a space right before the ending double quote. But I'm seeing that it might be a combination of spaces and special characters.

I've tried reading the documentation but I couldn't find anything and haven't found another question similar that has been answered or where the solution worked.

If you have a link to another article I could check out that would be great or a solution that would be extremely helpful!

Thank you!

Comment: Although I got it to work using xcopy I would still like to figure out why this is happening in robocopy

Comment: I'm interested in this question, `robocopy` offers other functionalities like `log` and control over the copying mechanism, which `xcopy` doesn't provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try **xcopy**

```
xcopy /S /I /E "source path" "destination path"
```

for more usage of **xcopy** [visit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)

Comment: This actually worked! Well it's currently working lol the source contains roughly over 100,000 files but it definitely is working! Thank you!

Comment: yes, im also using this command to copy the folder with sub-folders and files.

Comment: **C H E E R S**